# Do I need a "likelihood Jacobian" for point estimation?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, point-estimation

#### Scenario 1

Suppose that you work in a lumber yard and are given the following measurements of the *weights* of various pieces of lumber:

`x = [10, 26, 28, 13, 16, 7]`

You are asked to assume that $X$ is normally distributed and provide the maximum-likelihood estimate for the mean $\mu$ of $X$. So, you construct the likelihood function
$$L(\mu, \sigma) = \prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right)$$
where $f(x)$ is the pdf for $X$, in this case the normal pdf.

Taking the logarithm, differentiating with respect to $\mu$, and setting equal to zero, it is easy to show that the MLE for $\mu$ is the sample mean $\bar x = 16.67$.

#### Scenario 2

Again, you are asked to assume that the weight $X$ is normally distributed and compute the MLE of its mean. However, in this case, instead of being given $X$, you are given $Y$, the *radius* of each piece of lumber:

`y = [0.56, 0.91, 0.94, 0.64, 0.71, 0.47`

The lumber pieces are perfectly cylindrical and have identical density $\rho = 1$ and length $h = 10$; therefore, you can compute (deterministically) each piece's weight using the formula $x_i = \pi y_i^2 h\rho$, to obtain

`x = [10, 26, 28, 13, 16, 7]`

(exactly the same numbers as before).

**In scenario 2, what is the appropriate likelihood function?**

- According to one argument, since $x$ and $y$ are related by a known function, we need to multiply $f(x)$ by the appropriate Jacobian determinant:
  $$f(x)| dx/ dy| = f(x) 2\pi y h \rho = f(x) 2\pi \left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{\pi h \rho}}\right) h \rho$$
  The expression on the right—call it $\tilde f(x)$—comes from solving $x = \pi y^2 h\rho$ for $y$ and substituting it in. This yields the likelihood function
  $$\tilde L(\mu, \sigma) = \prod_{i=1}^n \tilde f(x_i)$$
  and now the MLE for $\mu$ is **not** $\bar x$, but some other quantity.
- According to another argument, since $x$ and $y$ are perfect mutually determinative, our measurements of $Y$ are "as good as" measurements of $X$. If we are interested in estimating the distribution of $X$, then we can compute the $\mu$ that maximizes
  $$L(\mu, \sigma) = \prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i)$$
  and therefore, the MLE for $\mu$ **is** $\bar x$ just as before.

It seems intuitive to me that the second answer is correct *as long as* we retain the assumption that $X$ (not $Y$) is normally distributed. Indeed, if this is *not* the case, then there are a lot of bad statistical estimates out there, because all sorts of scientific measurements (e.g. temperature) are actually monotonic, sometimes nonlinear transformations of other random variables (e.g. mercury level in a thermometer).

However, I was criticized for making this assumption in [another question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/597384/estimating-the-distribution-of-x-from-observations-of-z-operatornamefoo); hence, I am asking separately here.

---

N.B. To ensure that $x_i = \pi y_i^2 h\rho$ is invertible, we assume all radius measurements are positive. Technically this rules out the possibility of $X$ being normally distributed, but the example was chosen for ease of illustration; it is not difficult to come up with a relationship (e.g.
$X = Y^3$) between $X$ and $Y$ that avoids this issue.

I have omitted the computations for the MLE for $\sigma$ for brevity, but the same arguments apply.

Comment: @whuber I have created a separate question to address your comments in my question from yesterday.

Comment: The MLE _should be the same_ since the Jacobian does not involve the unknown parameter.

Comment: Thank you. I see exactly what you mean, and this comment helped me edit the relevant assumption into my original question.